# how to change date to local from epoch in value formatter function of dygraph

Tags: javascript, date, dygraphs

I am using dygraph for one of my project, i am making use of valueFormatter function to change my data to seconds from  milliseconds, the problem is my date(in this pic 1448821800)) is also getting changed to epoch. I want to display my date in yyyy/mm/dd format. How can i achieve this?

Here is the screenshot of the graph
[image]

and the javascript code for valueFormatter function is:

```js
valueFormatter: function(num){return (num/1000);}
```

Comment: Was it outputting the date as a date before, or always in epoch time?

Comment: it was outputting as a date before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rely on the values in the other parts being below a certain threshold, you could use the following:

```
valueFormatter: function(num){
    if (num > 100000000) {
        return moment(num).format()
    }

    return (num / 1000);
}
```

Though looking at the source of [this example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/value-axis-formatters.html), I think it might be possible to be more specific and less hacky by only adjusting the valueFormatter for specific axes. To help you with this would need to see more of your dygraph initialisation code though.

Answer makes use of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). An example of the above function can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0t904cs/).

Comment: its not working, as soon as i write the above code i do not get any data

Comment: Did you include the moment library?

Comment: yes i included the moment library but then also its not working

Comment: Can you see any javascript error being brought up in Firebug or developer tools?

Comment: got it, had few bugs, fixed it.

Comment: As the answer hints, you should set `valueFormatter` just for the x-axis. See the dygraphs docs on [per-axis options](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html). In this case it would be `{ axes: { x: { valueFormatter: ... } } }`.